# Subset list by name of element in list

Tags: r, list, subset

If I have a list like so:

```
x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)
df = cbind(x,y)
mylist=list(trace=df)
```

How can I pull out the trace data.frame by name? I've tried

```
trace_df = data.frame(mylist[mylist=='trace'])
```

but this searches through the list for data values equal to trace not for elements named list.

My thought behind this is that I have a large list of 7 or 8 elements and the position might change of them. So `trace` might be in index spot 1 or 2 or 5. So to make my code more reproducible I'd like to just search for the term `trace` and not search by index.

Answer (score 3):

Pull it out with either `mylist$trace` or `mylist[['trace']]`.

Answer (score 3):

if its single element then use

```
mylist["trace"]
```

if you want to select multiple elements from list then,

```
name = c("trace")

mylist[name]
```