# plotting a list of grobs

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

**DISCLOSURE:** I'm not sure how to make a reproducible example for this question.

I'm trying to plot a list of grobs using the `gridExtra` package.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
## Make Graphic Objects for Spec and raw traces
for (i in 1:length(morletPlots)){
  gridplots_Spec[[i]]=ggplotGrob(morletPlots[[i]])
  gridplots_Raw[[i]]=ggplotGrob(rawPlot[[i]])
  gridplots_Raw[[i]]$widths=gridplots_Spec[[i]]$widths
}
names(gridplots_Spec)=names(morletPlots)
names(gridplots_Raw)=names(rawPlot)

## Combine spec and Raw traces
g=list()
for (i in 1:length(rawPlot)){
    g[[i]]=arrangeGrob(gridplots_Spec[i],gridplots_Raw[i],heights=c(4/5,1/5))
}

numPlots = as.numeric(length(g))

##Plot both
for (i in 1:numPlots){

  grid.draw(g[i],ncol=2)
}
```

Let me walk through the code.

`morletPlots` = a list of ggplots

`rawplot` = A list of ggplots

`gridplots_spec` and `gridplots_Raw` = list of grobs from the ggplots made above.

`g` = a list of the two grobs above combined so combining `gridplots_spec[1]` and `gridplots_raw[1]` so on and so on for the length of the list.

now my goal would be two plot all of those into 2 columns. But whenever I pass the `gridplots_spec[i]` through the grid.draw loop I get an error:

`Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"`

I can't unlist it becasue it just turns into a long character vector. any ideas?

If it's absolutely crucial I can spend the time to make an reproducible example but I'm more likely just missing a simple step.

Comment: Look up the difference between `[[` and `[`. Try `grid.draw(g[[i]])`

Comment: I did that I get, `Error in gList(list(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Comment: Well, you have the same mistake in the preceding `for` loop.

Comment: The errors are telling you what's wrong. Again Roland is right. You are using a single bracket when you should be using two. You did the same thing in a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869978/subset-list-by-name-of-element-in-list. Do not use single brackets to access elements of a list.

Comment: more than a simple step missing, it appears your code suffers from a number of misunderstandings of some functions you use, so it would really be worthwhile to spend the time making a minimal reproducible example. It's probably more time-efficient in the long term, as you'll understand better what every function is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of your script, if it's not the intended result you may want to use some bits and pieces to make your question reproducible.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

morletPlots <- replicate(5, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE)
rawplot <- replicate(5, ggplot(), simplify = FALSE)

glets <- lapply(morletPlots, ggplotGrob)
graws <- lapply(rawplot, ggplotGrob)

rawlet <- function(raw, let, heights=c(4,1)){
  g <- rbind(let, raw)
  panels <- g$layout[grepl("panel", g$layout$name), ]
#  g$heights <- grid:::unit.list(g$heights) # not needed
  g$heights[unique(panels$t)] <- lapply(heights, unit, "null")
  g
}

combined <- mapply(rawlet, raw = graws, let=glets, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(grobs=combined, ncol=2)
```

[image]

*Edit* I can't resist this mischievous hack to colour the plots for illustration; feel free to ignore it.

```
palette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Pastel1"))
ggplot.numeric = function(i) ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=i))

morletPlots <- lapply(1:5, ggplot)
rawplot <- lapply(1:5, ggplot)
```

[image]

Comment: I've been haunting SO for examples of how to resize the heights on grobs, and repeatedly when I try to run them - including the example here, run exactly as written - I get variations on this error:

 Error in `[<-.unit`(`*tmp*`, unique(panels$t), value = list(4, 1)) : 
  Value being assigned must be a unit

Is there some change in gtable that requires an update to this code?